# Formatting the string YYYYMMDD as YYYY.MM.DD using Boost

Tags: c++, boost, string-formatting

I have a `std::string` such as `20040531`, I want to format this as `2004.05.31`.

Apart from the straight forward way of doing an `std::insert` at respective locations, is there a better way to do this using Boost?

PS. I cannot use other Boost calls to get date/time as this string is returned via a custom API. So this question is reduced to basic string formatting which may not sound exciting, but I am trying to learn Boost.

Comment: Why use Boost? Why not just Why not just do `a.substr(0,4) + "." + a.substr(4,2) + "." + a.substr(6,2)`?

Comment: No good reason, just trying to do same things differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/format/doc/format.html)...

```
#include <string> 
#include "boost/format.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a("20040531");
    std::cout << boost::format("%1%.%2%.%3%") 
                    % a.substr(0,4) % a.substr(4,2) % a.substr(6,2);
}
```

You specifically asked about doing this using Boost, but if you wanted to do this in C++ without introducing a dependency on Boost then you could just use a stream to achieve the same thing:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream s;
    std::string a("20040531");
    s << a.substr(0,4) << '.' << a.substr(4,2) << '.' << a.substr(6,2);
    std::cout << s.str();
}
```

Comment: Cheers! I have to ask the inevitable at the risk of appearing daft. Is there a tutorial which explains "how" to use boost::format, i did search for it, but could not get anything relevant.

Comment: The [link I posted to the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) contains a good explanation and many examples.